# Nuget Readonly Resources

Tags: c#, nuget, t4

I'm creating a DTO generator to be shared between projects I have a ttinclude file with some logic in it. In my nuspec I'm including files like so:

```
<files>
  <file src="T4Generators\AutoMapperExtensions.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\AutoMapperExtensions.ttinclude"/>
  <file src="T4Generators\ConstGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\ConstGenerator.ttinclude"/>
  <file src="T4Generators\DTOGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\DTOGenerator.ttinclude"/>
  <file src="T4Generators\EnumGenerator.ttinclude" target="content\T4Generators\EnumGenerator.ttinclude"/>
</files>
```

Is there a way to make these files read-only,  since they are shared between projects people have a tendency to make changes to the include instead of going to my source (this is an internal resource).

Comment: Could probably run a Powershell script in `install.ps1` to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `install.ps1`. It is soon going to go away and quite honestly it is not a good practice to make changes to a user's system on installing a nuget package

Comment: @johnny 5, make them read only how? you mean the user should not be able to edit the file from the explorer?

Comment: no from visual studio by default

Comment: Looks like they [didn't like the idea](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1729). It took them 2 years to realize that. The question was still under consideration when you asked here.